# expo build:ios throws Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Yesterday I managed to run the command expo build:ios successfully but this morning it just won't work, I get the following error message after entering my credentials:

```
Trying to authenticate with Apple Developer Portal...
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate 
verify failed"
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Any idea where the error comes from? I've checked the apple services status and everything is up.

Here's my setup

```
Expo CLI 3.11.5 environment info:
System:
  OS: macOS 10.14.5
  Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
  Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  @storybook/react-native: ^4.1.7 => 4.1.7 
  @types/react: 16.4.7 => 16.4.7 
  @types/react-native: ^0.60.2 => 0.60.2 
  @types/react-navigation: ^3.0.7 => 3.0.7 
  expo: ^33.0.0 => 33.0.7 
  react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz => 0.59.8 
  react-navigation: ^4.0.10 => 4.0.10 
npmGlobalPackages:
  expo-cli: 3.11.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://status.expo.io/incidents/vw27kb523vn7?u=mgkr96ykcctd

Turns out [it's a known issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMbNL.png). One of Expo's certificates expired.

[image: IMG]

Comment: yes, I did. This might be an issue on Apple's side then?

Comment: Edited my answer with a link. (If you could select it as correct that would help me out a lot :) )

Comment: The temp fix (manually replacing the cert locally) worked for me, btw. https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/1436#issuecomment-574101538

Comment: This answer has outdated. This bug has been officially fixed. run `npm install -g expo-cli` to update.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

My woking solution :

npm install -g expo-cli

Answer (score 0):

## go into the `node_modules` of your expo-cli

cd `npm root -g`/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin/traveling-fastlane-1.10.0-osx/lib/ruby/lib

## verify that the ca-bundle.crt is actually expired

openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ca-bundle.crt

## directory of your openssl cert_file

cert_file="$( openssl version -d | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' )/cert.pem"

## backup expired crt

cp ca-bundle.crt ca-bundle.crt.bak

## copy your openssl cert file

cp $cert_file ca-bundle.crt

Comment: hacker_status++

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, these 2 commands will do the tricks 1)which expo to locate expo in your Mac which will give you this "/usr/local/bin/expo" 2) "cd /usr/local/bin/" 3)-rm expo 4)-rm expo-cli

Then re-install the latest version of expo-cli or at least the 3.11.7

Answer (score 0):

The solution above `npm install -g expo-cli` is correct.
I just want to add DO NOT use `yarn global add expo-cli` since it did not work.